# Retrofit2 Inconsistency Response from Server

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am new to Android development and learning how to use `Retrofit` and I am having a hard time to deal with inconsistency response from the server.

There are more than two kinds of responses will be returned from the server.

May I know how to deal with this kind of server response?
Should I create different data class to handle it based on the server response?

---

## Server Response

**Result - Success**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "code": null,
    "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "created_at": "2018-07-12 15:25:42",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-12 15:25:42"
    }
}
```

**Result - Fail**

```
{
    "status": false,
    "code": null,
    "result": "Server error."
}
```

**Result - Validation**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "code": null,
    "result": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

---

## Android

### Message Model

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class Errors (
        @Json(name = "status") val status: Boolean?,
        @Json(name = "code") val code: Int?,
        @Json(name = "result") val message: Objects?
)
```

Comment: you can use an adapter to transform your response and create a custom object

Comment: ultimately, this is poor api structure. but yea, you'll need an adapter to transform

Comment: @crgarridos, would you mind to show me how to do so?

Comment: @ElliotM, I am using a framework to create the API, so I do not have too much control on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'result' key multiple time depends on response state like this

```
`       @Json(name = "status") val status: Boolean?,
        @Json(name = "code") val code: Int?,
        @Json(name = "result") val message: String?,
        @Json(name = "result") val result: ResultObject?,
        @Json(name = "result") val validation: HashMap<String,List<String>>?
`
```

and depends on ur 'status' key you can get the correct values from the correct 'result' key by making a conditions.